# How to change the size of the font of a JLabel to take the maximum size

Tags: java, fonts, size, containers, jlabel

I have a `JLabel` in a Container.
The defaut size of the font is very small.
I would like that the text of the `JLabel` to take the maximum size.

How can I do that?

Comment: @animatrix30: your question doesn't make much sense.  Do you want the horizontal size or the vertical size to match the JLabel's size (or both)?  Does this need to be automated: that is, if you decide to make your JLabel, say, wider, should the font automatically grow?  Why do you want to do that?  It is an uncommon request.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? show a big Font ? or re size the font per component size?

Comment: My Container juste have one element : the JLabel.
By defaut the jlabel take all the place.

However, the font size is very small.
I would like that the font size will be maximal, in order to have the less "white" possible.

@ring bearer I want to have the biggest FOnt possible for this Jlabel

I hope you have understood what I've tried to explain :)

Comment: @WizardOfOdds should the font automatically grow : Yes exactly what I want. I'm doing that because my application is for handicapped

Comment: The question makes perfect sense. I'm using it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4437998/11236

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Not the most pretty code, but the following will pick an appropriate font size for a `JLabel` called `label` such that the text inside will fit the interior as much as possible without overflowing the label:

```
Font labelFont = label.getFont();
String labelText = label.getText();

int stringWidth = label.getFontMetrics(labelFont).stringWidth(labelText);
int componentWidth = label.getWidth();

// Find out how much the font can grow in width.
double widthRatio = (double)componentWidth / (double)stringWidth;

int newFontSize = (int)(labelFont.getSize() * widthRatio);
int componentHeight = label.getHeight();

// Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
int fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, componentHeight);

// Set the label's font size to the newly determined size.
label.setFont(new Font(labelFont.getName(), Font.PLAIN, fontSizeToUse));
```

Basically, the code looks at how much space the text in the [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) takes up by using the [`FontMetrics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) object, and then uses that information to determine the largest font size that can be used without overflowing the text from the `JLabel`.

The above code can be inserted into perhaps the `paint` method of the `JFrame` which holds the `JLabel`, or some method which will be invoked when the font size needs to be changed.

The following is an screenshot of the above code in action:

[image]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/growing-text.png))</sub>

Comment: You can't really do this. The font won't exist until the JLabel, in this case, is first drawn. Otherwise, you get NPE's if you try to do this in the wrong order of initialization/resizing/drawing.

Comment: The code should be in validate(), not paint(), because changing the font invalidate the Component which trigger a call to paint(), so swing is endlessly repainting the component, using a lot of cpu.

Comment: Note that `label.getHeight()` is indirectly documented as using **pixel** units while `font.getSize()` returns a value in [point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getSize--) units. Might `componentHeight` need use `label.getHeight() * PPI / dpi` so that `Math.min` returns points, not pixels, in both cases?

Answer (score 123):

```
label = new JLabel("A label");
label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

taken from [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Answer (score 10):

```
 JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("<html><span style='font-size:20px'>"+Text+"</span></html>");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
label.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
```

Comment: only code answers are discouraged. it will be great if you add some description on how this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Source Code for Label - How to change Color and Font (in Netbeans)

```
jLabel1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));


jLabel1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Falemnderit @Bekim Fetaji

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to point out that the accepted answer has a couple of limitations (which I discovered when I tried to use it)

1. As written, it actually keeps recalculating the font size based on a ratio of the ***previous*** font size... thus after just a couple of calls it has  rendered the font size as much too large.  (eg Start with 12 point as your DESIGNED Font, expand the label by just 1 pixel, and the published code will calculate the Font size as 12 * (say) 1.2 (ratio of field space to text) = 14.4 or 14 point font.  1 more Pixel and call and you are at 16 point !).

It is thus not suitable (without adaptation) for use in a repeated-call setting (eg a `ComponentResizedListener`, or a custom/modified `LayoutManager`).

The listed code effectively assumes a starting size of 10 pt but refers to the current font size and is thus suitable for calling once (to set the size of the font when the label is created).  It would work better in a multi-call environment if it did `int newFontSize = (int) (widthRatio * 10);` rather than `int newFontSize = (int)(labelFont.getSize() * widthRatio);`

2. Because it uses `new Font(labelFont.getName(), Font.PLAIN, fontSizeToUse))` to generate the new font, there is no support for Bolding, Italic or Color etc from the original font in the updated font.  It would be more flexible if it made use of `labelFont.deriveFont` instead.
3. The solution does not provide support for HTML label Text.  (I know that was probably not ever an intended outcome of the answer code offered, but as I had an HTML-text `JLabel` on my `JPanel` I formally discovered the limitation. The `FontMetrics.stringWidth()` calculates the text length as **inclusive** of the width of the html tags - ie as simply more text)

I recommend looking at the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814616/how-to-auto-adjust-font-size-of-multiple-jlabel-based-on-container-size-in-a-smo/9815307#9815307) where trashgod's answer points to a number of different answers (including this one) to an almost identical question.  On that page I will provide an additional answer that speeds up one of the other answers by a factor of 30-100.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this its worked for me:

```
Label welcomeMsg = new JLabel("Contact us");

welcomeMsg.setBounds(200,10,100,25);

welcomeMsg.setFont( new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,22));
```