# Not able to render form fields using itext+flying saucer

Tags: java, html, itext, flying-saucer

I am using iText and flying saucer to create PDF from XHTML.When I see my output PDF I don't see the Input text boxes,check boxed ,radio buttons,drop down boxes and buttons which are in my XHTML page.To say literally I don't see any of the HTML except paragraphs in my output PDF. Is there any way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve this issue by using [YAHP-Converter](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/).Thanks to post by @RealHowTo [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133581/html-to-pdf-using-itext-how-can-produce-a-checkbox)
I recommand this over Flying Saucer.