# HTML to PDF - How to display checkbox using itext XMLWorker

Tags: css, checkbox, itext, html-to-pdf

I am trying to display checkbox using XML worker but unable to do so. I have also tried through CSS but still not able to display the same when converting HTML to PDF. I am using "itextpdf-5.4.2.jar" and "xmlworker-5.4.1.jar". Request you to please help me with an alternative solution other than YaHP Converter because i already completed 90% of my coding. Thanks in advance !!!!

Following is the sample HTML code which i have tried:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>

label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    content:"\2713";
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
    content:"\2713";
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div class="checkbox">  
        <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" CHECKED/> 
        <label for="check1">Checkbox No. 1</label>  
        <br/>  
        <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2"/>  
        <label for="check2">Checkbox No. 2</label>  
        <br/>  
        <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check" value="check3" checked/>  
        <label for="check3">Checkbox No. 3</label>  
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Following is the output in PDF:

Checkbox No. 1

Checkbox No. 2

Checkbox No. 3

Answer (score 3):

Check this question in stackoverflow.[HTML to PDF using iText : How can produce a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133581/html-to-pdf-using-itext-how-can-produce-a-checkbox) 
using the Unicode '&#x2610' character you can create.