# How to change JLabel font size to fill JPanel free space while resizing?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

There is a similar question here:
[How to change the size of the font of a JLabel to take the maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size)

but it doesn't work in backwards.

So if you make `JPanel` bigger, font is growing, but if you make it smaller `JLabel` size and font remain as before

[Check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR0rT.png)

How to make `Jlabel` font growing according to `JPanel` size while resizing?

Comment: Did you try modyifying the code to fix the problem when the frame size shrinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is answer.

Let's take the code from here: [How to change the size of the font of a JLabel to take the maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size), answer from **coobird**

```
int componentWidth = label.getWidth();
```

We need to get width from the `JFrame` component, NOT from `JLabel`, because the code will no let opportunity to change size for the JLabel.

this will fix it:

```
int componentWidth = this.getWidth()-20; // '20' - according width of Jlabel to JFrame
```

Comment: for Container.getSize/getBounds you have to add Swing Timer, to avoiding caused flickering, only call for restart untill resize not ended,

Comment: Why `20`; shouldn't this be based on `FontMetrics`?

Answer (score 4):

by using [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) and [TextLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/2d/spec/j2d-fonts.html) you can get this output (please read an comment in the code)

[SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#computeStringWidth%28java.awt.FontMetrics,%20java.lang.String%29) can do that correctly too

I sugget to add a few pixels moreover on both directions

add [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to the container and on componentResized event recalculate FontMetrics again

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShowFontMetrics extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel lTime;

    public ShowFontMetrics() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        lTime = new JLabel("88:88");
        lTime.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 88));
        FontMetrics fm = lTime.getFontMetrics(lTime.getFont());
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(lTime.getText(), lTime.getFont(), fm.getFontRenderContext());
        Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
        Dimension d = lTime.getPreferredSize();
        d.height = (int) (bounds.getHeight() + 100);// add huge amount of pixels just for for fun
        d.width = (int) (bounds.getWidth() + 150);// add huge amount of pixels just for for fun
        lTime.setPreferredSize(d);
        lTime.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lTime.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        pane.add(lTime);
        setContentPane(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        ShowFontMetrics frame = new ShowFontMetrics();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. But it doesn't do what I meant.. The font of JLable have to be changed after JFrame resized. So if you make JFrame bigger/smaller - JLabel font has to be changed as well..

Comment: There's a related example that does this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).

Comment: I updated my answer (probably I not read your question...) for CompomentListener,

Comment: @mKorbel still not working. Where is dynamic font setting? You set font: lTime.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 88)); So it static...

Answer (score 4):

Like this?
http://java-sl.com/tip_adapt_label_font_size.html

UPDATE:

The code as requested

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class ResizeLabelFont extends JLabel {
    public static final int MIN_FONT_SIZE=3;
    public static final int MAX_FONT_SIZE=240;
    Graphics g;

    public ResizeLabelFont(String text) {
        super(text);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                adaptLabelFont(ResizeLabelFont.this);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void adaptLabelFont(JLabel l) {
        if (g==null) {
            return;
        }
        Rectangle r=l.getBounds();
        int fontSize=MIN_FONT_SIZE;
        Font f=l.getFont();

        Rectangle r1=new Rectangle();
        Rectangle r2=new Rectangle();
        while (fontSize<MAX_FONT_SIZE) {
            r1.setSize(getTextSize(l, f.deriveFont(f.getStyle(), fontSize)));
            r2.setSize(getTextSize(l, f.deriveFont(f.getStyle(),fontSize+1)));
            if (r.contains(r1) && ! r.contains(r2)) {
                break;
            }
            fontSize++;
        }

        setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle(),fontSize));
        repaint();
    }

    private Dimension getTextSize(JLabel l, Font f) {
        Dimension size=new Dimension();
        g.setFont(f);
        FontMetrics fm=g.getFontMetrics(f);
        size.width=fm.stringWidth(l.getText());
        size.height=fm.getHeight();

        return size;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.g=g;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ResizeLabelFont label=new ResizeLabelFont("Some text");
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Resize label font");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this answer is old but it's also a link-only one. Can you copy the needed information from the link.