# Frame image scaling

Tags: java

I'm using code:

```
main.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("4.jpg")).getScaledInstance(main.getContentPane().getWidth(), main.getContentPane().getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));
```

to set the image.problem is,it's not on the full frame

[image]

and having 1 more problem when I'm designing GUI in the NetBeans IDE,the picture is overlapping the components. [image]

plz suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use layout manager. Without layout manager it will be difficult to resize components manually. Check these links [Resize the components of the frame in full-screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815922/resize-the-components-of-the-frame-in-full-screen-mode) & [Visual Guide to Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). IMHO what you need is either Grid Layout or Border Layout.

Comment: i'm using main.setContentPane and default layout by netbeans ide is free layout or some thing like that then why do i need to set Grid Layout or Border Layout.