# How can I scale text to fit the container?

Tags: java, swing, text, scaling

Here's the problem: I have a drawing area that will display graphics (custom drawing). When the application is first started, no graphics are selected to be drawn, and the drawing area is set to a default (preferred) size. So as not to confuse the user, I'd like to display some text (something like "No Image Selected") until the real graphics are drawn. The drawing window is contained in a JScrollPane, so it can also be resized. Is there a way to add text (a JLabel?) to the drawing area and have it automatically scale to fill the extent of the drawing area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the link http://java-sl.com/tip_adapt_label_font_size.html

It shows how to adapt `JLabel's` font size when it's resized.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to add your JLabel to the JScrollPane Component after sizing the label's font size to your needs.  See below:

```
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jLabel1);
```

The second solution in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size) really does a great job of laying how to scale the font size to a container... just replace the String width with your JScrollPane.  Since it is inherited from JComponent, you can just use getWidth like so:

```
jScrollPane1.getWidth();
```