# Change JLabel Font size

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, jlabel

I was trying to change the font size of `JLabel`, I tried to set `Font` but it is always the same!

Here is some of the code:

```
 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
 super.paint(g);
 Container cont=this.getContentPane();
 intro=new JLabel("משחק זיכרון");
 intro.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
 intro.setFont(intro.getFont().deriveFont(64.0f));
 intro.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
 cont.add(intro);
     }
```

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size

Comment: I saw it ! but still not useful all the methods they describe I use it !!!

Comment: It's not a good idea to change your widget's properties in the `paint` method. At this point in the code, you should onyl draw the object as it is configured. If you want to change the label's properties, you should do it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: OK ! I did something wrong in my code !!! I write twice setfont and I didn't notice that !!!!! so it works perfectly ! thank you all !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are calling the wrong `deriveFont` method.

The parameter in `deriveFont(int)` is the style (bold, italic, etc.). The method you are looking for is `deriveFont(float)`.

In your case, the only change you need to make is `intro.setFont(intro.getFont().deriveFont(64.0f));`.

Here's a short code example that does display a label with font size 64:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
JLabel label = new JLabel ("Font Test");
label.setFont (label.getFont ().deriveFont (64.0f));
frame.getContentPane ().add (label);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack ();
frame.setVisible (true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't confuse the `deriveFont` method which expects a style argument over the one that [expects a font size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28float%29). The one that you're using uses the style argument and has no bearing on the actual font size. Instead use

```
intro.setFont(intro.getFont().deriveFont(64f));
```

Also don't add components in the `paint` method. Your currrent application will not display the `JLabel` until a repaint is done. Overriding `paint` (or more correctly `paintComponent` for Swing) is intended for custom painting but the adding components does not qualify as such.
 The application will have the overhead of the component being added *every time* a repaint is done.

Example:

[image]

```
public class LabelDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                JLabel intro = new JLabel("משחק זיכרון");
                frame.add(intro);
                intro.setFont(intro.getFont().deriveFont(64f));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you I found the problem ! it's not the way Iv'e wrote the code but I was not aware enough !