# I'm trying to underline text in a JLabel but nothing is working at all

Tags: java, text, jpanel, jlabel, underline

```
JLabel topCap = new JLabel ("  Top Caption");
txtTop = new JTextField("Enter top Caption here");
topCaption = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
viewerWindow.add(topCaption, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JLabel bottomCap = new JLabel ("  Bottom Caption");
txtBottom = new JTextField("Enter Bottom Caption here");
bottomCaption = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);
viewerWindow.add(bottomCaption,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I have another block of code in which when the user enters text into the `JTextField`, and presses the update JButton it is displayed to the JFrame. This works fine for all styles (italic and bold) except underline. I've looked everywhere and I found a block of code on stackoverflow but that didn't help either. In case you're wondering, this is the line of code that didn't work:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = label.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

I am thoroughly confused does anyone know what i should do?
Or at least what class i should look into?
thanks

Comment: Post a [mcve] to explain what's not working

Comment: @Reimeus I'm not exactly sure at all what's not working. when i use the block of code that i put at the bottom, i get an error message saying "cannot find class Map", but i went to the Java Library and could not find any class Map there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import TextAttribute from awt

```
java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
```

You can use HTML to underline. But for faster rendering than HTML, you should stick to your method.

```
JLabel.setText("<HTML><U>Underlined Text</U></HTML>");
```

Comment: I have already imported that, and still no luck.

Comment: can you post the exact error message or explain what's not being executed?

Comment: there is no error message, just the JLabel that is on screen does not change at all. I have a JRadioButton that when pressed, should change the text in the JLabel to be underlined. I have the ActionListener attached correctly because i have tested it with other font styles (bold and italic).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use HTML inside JLabel. As a example you can do like this.

```
JLabel label=new JLabel();
label.setText("<html><u>Underlined Label</u></html>");
```

Comment: and if i want to change the size as well as underline would i invoke the setFont method then?

Comment: In that case I think you can take a tip from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size)

Comment: It is not working in my case. I am using WindowsClassicLookAndFeel. With default L&F it works. So it is a bug.